# PDE: Fokker-Planck equation with time-dependent boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, greens-function

We have the following PDE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t}= - a\frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} + \frac{D}{2} \frac{ \partial^2 p(x,t) }{\partial x^2}, \quad0<x<L, \quad t>0  
\end{equation} 
where $a$ and $D$ are constants.
We also  have the following initial and boundary conditions: 
\begin{equation}
p(x,0)=0, \hspace{5mm}
a p(x,t)- \frac{D}{2} \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} = f(t) \quad at \quad x=0, \hspace{5mm}
\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=0 \quad at \quad x=L
\end{equation}

The expression, $\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=0$, is not a standard well-known boundary condition and makes the PDE difficult to solve. I would be grateful if anyone have any idea or comment for analytically solving this PDE.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce this problem to a more familiar one with the following trick. Consider the problem
$$
q_t(x,t) = -au_x(x,t) + \frac{D}{2}q_{xx}(x,t) \quad (0 < t, 0 < x < 2L)\\
q(x,0) = 0, \quad aq(0,t) - \frac{D}{2}q_x(0,t) = f(t) =  -aq(2L,t) - \frac{D}{2}q_x(2L,t)
$$
and solve it with a standard method. The solution will have a specific symmetry about the line $\{x = L\}$ by uniqueness, namely it will satisfy $q(x,t) = -q(2L-x,t)$. This implies that $q_{xx}(L,t) = 0$ for all $t$.

Then set $p(x,t) = q(x,t)$ for $t >0, 0 < x < L$ and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I just put $\frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}=0$ into the PDE to get a first order boundary condition? And which method  do you recommend for the reduced problem of yours? Duhamel's theorem?

Comment: @HosseinHosseini - you could try to use separation of variables.